# Why doesn't a PHP regex return an array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

My code is supposed to return an array containing a weather summary, but does not.

How can I make this work?

This is part of a course I'm taking on `Udemy.com`; my code exactly matches my instructor's, but doesn't return the same results.

I didn't find any syntax errors so there is something else that I'm either missing or nescient of..

```
$contents=file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/San-Francisco/forecasts/latest");

preg_match('3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class="phrase">(.*?)</s', $contents, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: You'll need to show us your php code if we are to help.

Comment: The content of the "file" may have changed format, which would make the way you're trying to extract the weather information, no longer useable. What you're being shown how to do is called screen scraping, and it's pretty frowned upon when it's not your site or content to scrape. Probably suggest you ask for a refund and start a different course =/

Comment: In his specific example, he is showing us how to make a weather scraper; not for the purpose of using it in nefarious ways; just to teach us php and regex.  As for a refund, I have considered it but I'm the kind of person who likes to finish what I start.  Also, right now, I can't afford to purchase another course.  I've already invested most of my money in software and courses and have bet the farm at being able to learn this material and make a career of it.  Thank you for your response though

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some delimeter around your regex to seperate it from (possible) modifiers.
You could use any char you want - ie `/` - but as you use this chars inside your regex it would maybe be easier to use something different like the tilde `~`

```
$contents=file_get_contents("http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/San-Francisco/forecasts/latest");

preg_match('~3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b><span class="phrase">(.*?)</s~', $contents, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Just tested your regex and it seems, the html of the page doesn't match your expression. I slightly modified it as follows:

```
3 Day Weather Forecast Summary:<\/b>.*?<span class="phrase">([^<]+)
```

Comment: The instructor told us to use (.*?) to find the contents between two phrases

Comment: I found a fix; apparently the site updated since the instructor created the video and I need to change this phrase:  <span class="phrase">(.*?)</s'    into: <span class="phrase">(.*?)<\/span/s'  in order to make it work.  Thank you to all who made an effort to help me with this problem.  I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: @Veniversum have you tested my solution? I did, and it worked. You just hear to use the regex in your code an add the tilde around it.